# Changing the name of a variable in pojo class into a user input value in kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin, gson

I googled for a few days now and can't seem to find an answer.

How can I change the variable name of a `pojo` class to display a user input instead?

Here is the code:

```
private fun writeJSONtoFile(s: String) {

    //This is the save function in the result data page
    val unit_result = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.unit_result)
    val mReading = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.mReading_result)

    val unit_res: String = unit_result.text.toString()
    val reading_Res: String = mReading.text.toString()

    //Create a Object of Gson
    var gson = Gson()


    val unit=Unit(reading_Res,"20:55")
    //And so on,
    val building=Building(listOf(unit))
    //Until the outer part of the structure
    val solstice=Solstice(building)


    //for (i in 1..2) {
    //}

    //Convert the Json object to JsonString
    var jsonString:String = gson.toJson(solstice)


    //Initialize the File Writer and write into file
    val file = File(s)


    try {

        FileOutputStream(file, false).bufferedWriter().use { writer -> writer.write((jsonString)) }
        //fileOutputStream.write(data.toByteArray())


    } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }




}
```

Here are the classes:

```
package com.example.watermeterapp

data class Solstice(
    var building:Building
)

data class Building(
    var id: List<Unit>
)

data class Unit(
    var reading: String,
    var timeStamp: String
)
```

Expected result:

> {"Building":{"A-01-013":[{"Reading":"123123.42"}]}}

Actual Result:

> {"Building":{"id":[{"Reading":"123123.42"}]}}

Is there any way to change the "id" into any user input?Is it possible in `kotlin`? Would like to know, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to change field names dynamically. However, you can use `JSONObject` instead to construct your objects. For example:

```
val unit = JSONObject()
unit.put("Reading", reading_Res)
val building = JSONObject()
building.put(userInput, listOf(unit))
```

This would yield: (assuming `userInput = "A-01-013"`)

```
{"A-01-013":[{"Reading":"123123.42"}]}
```

Then, to match it to your expected result, you can simply wrap it in another `JSONObject`:

```
val wrapper = JSONObject()
wrapper.put("Building", building)
```

Which results in:

```
{"Building":{"A-01-013":[{"Reading":"123123.42"}]}}
```

To get the string representation of this JSON object, you can simply use the `toString()` method:

```
writer.write(wrapper.toString())
```

Comment: Hi @Christilyn, thank you for the answer, I appreciate it a lot, it was great and it was very close but now I'm getting the output of `{"Building":{"A-01-01":"[Unit(reading=123123.42, timeStamp=20:55)]"}}`

Comment: @John did you create a JSONObject for your Unit? you should create one similar to how you build the json for building. I've edited my answer to include this.

Comment: Oh ok thanks for that @Christilyn, it worked! Thank You so much. If I may ask, would there be a problem if say, I wanted to read this file?would it worked without pojo classes?

Comment: @John Yes you would still be able to read and parse it as a JSONObject so no pojo classes would be needed. You can re-create the JSONObject from a string like : `val myObj = JSONObject(jsonString)`